# Can we map inches on screen CSS accurately now?

Tags: css, media-queries, standards, toucaan

All right. This is an old one, but fun.

I know that we have `1in` physical unit mapped to `96px` on screen dpi. This mapping comes from way back in the 90s when monitors/screens used to be of a much lower resolve. That was a different time. Web was 'desktop only' utility then and as one would suspect implementations today haven't kept pace with the new [landscape of the web](https://bubblin.io/blog/the-new-landscape-of-the-web).

Circa 2020.

I want to declare a css variable `--inch` at the `:root` of my webpage and map it to absolute inches for different devices using media queries. I can do that on the devices that I currently own, like so:

```
/* css */
:root {
   --inch: 130px; /* this value is from my Macbook Pro 2017 for example. */
}

.square {
  width: var(--inch);
  height: var(--inch);
  background: red;
}
```

And then with a ruler I measured the dimensions of the square on the screen. I even made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/marvindanig/pen/YzyKzxL) for this to test and compare absolute inch with the `in` unit supported by your browser/machine.

Now. How should we go about setting `--inch` variable across mobile, watchos, iPads, desktops and if possible TVs and projectors as well?

---

UPDATE 1: Nailed the scope a little bit.

The following `media-queries` cover the wide selection of screens available on market. This list is from 2013 ([credits](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)) and may not be exhaustive but could be improved upon:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

  /* Small screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 320px) { 

  /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

  /* Medium screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 700px) { 

  /* Medium screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

  /* Large screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 1300px) { 

  /* Large screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

The following clause handles pixel to `--inch` mapping for all retina MBPs of 2017, for example.

```
@media (resolution: 192dpi) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  :root {
    --inch: 130px;
  }
}

.square {
  width: var(--inch);
  height: var(--inch);
  background: orangered;
}
```

Where the `--inch` variable implies real physical inch to measure. Notice that we are not using min/max on media-queries to fit in a range of screen dpis here. This mapping is exactly for MBP'17 only with a returned dpi of 192 and dpr of 2.

Comment: I am not sure what your end-goal is but is it (px to in) translatable in a straight-forward manner? First thought that came to mind that two MBPs (for example) can have a 15in screen size but if one has a retina display (4K or 5K) and the other one does not - wouldn't there be different `--inch` settings (that would yield different results)? - not sure you'd want to maintain a list of all screens available (in the world, for every device) - So maybe I do not understand your question or the approach.  Or maybe this approach is not really feasible in today's display landscape. Could you clarify?

Comment: In your pen, on screen ONE: the standard (blue) box measured 1in while the physical (red) one measured 1 3/8 in - on screen TWO; the standard (blue) box measured: 9/16 in while the physical (red) measured: 15/16in - this is just on my laptop with external monitor

Comment: a retina display would pack more pixels per inch, yes. there appears to be a media-query to tackle exactly that but I mean obviously it'd have been much better if vendors exposed those physical inch values in the global namespace somehow? this is just an exploratory exercise at the moment.

Comment: exactly! so the external monitor has a lower ppi but is mapped to 96px as per the old standard. and yet in physical terms the screen is like what 27" I believe?

Comment: I guess the point I am trying to make is that there is no (easy?) way to make the mapping universal given the infinite possible permutations (screen size, resolutions) out there - the closest way to make something look the same in all screens is by setting boundary points for the media queries and adjust your layout based on those boundaries

Comment: Look at @media `device-pixel-ratio` and `min-resolution`

Comment: @blurfus so if targeting UX/UI for the Apple watch we would probably end up querying min width: 320px to detect, but there are smartphones well under that width resolution point and yet the surface on a watch is sub-inch physically, so the ui definitions of mobile do not scale there. (just an example)

Comment: Completely agree, that's why I am trying to understand your end-goal since it might require different approaches (other than simply rely on px to in conversions) - interesting exploration exercise :)

Comment: Updated with a few possibilities. I wonder if it's possible to verify the `--inch` variable using the queries listed atop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to map css pixels to real physical inches now. It is cumbersome, obviously, but *possible*. To do this, we will use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) that are otherwise known as CSS variables, like so:

```css
/* 13.3-inch MBP (2012) (1280 x 800) */
@media (resolution: 96dpi) and (device-width: 1280px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 116px;
  }
}

/* 17" Retina MBP/Chrome values */
@media (resolution: 192dpi) and (device-width: 1680px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 130px;
  }
}

/* Windows 10 @100% (1366 x 768) landscape*/
@media (resolution: 96dpi) and (device-width: 1366px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 114px;
  }
}

/* Windows 10 Pro @100% (1920 x 1080px) landscape. */
@media (resolution: 96dpi) and (device-width: 1920px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 144px;
  }
}

/* Windows 10 Pro @125% (1920 x 1080px) landscape. */
@media (resolution: 120dpi) and (device-width: 1536px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 115px;
  }
}

/* 27" EIZO monitor (2560 x 1440)*/
@media (resolution: 115dpi) and (device-width: 2560px) {
  :root {
    --inch: 92px;
  }
}

/****************/
/* MOBILE ZONE */
/****************/

/* iPhone 11 Pro Max */

@media (device-width: 414px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) {
  :root {
    --inch: 370px;
  }
}

@media (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) {
  :root {
    --inch: 189px;
  }
}
/****************/
/* MOBILE ZONE */
/****************/

/* iPhone 11 Pro Max */

@media (device-width: 414px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) {
  :root {
    --inch: 370px;
  }
}

@media (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) {
  :root {
    --inch: 189px;
  }
}

/* …and so on. */
```

Hardware-specific mappings for all the major devices on the market or those you wish to support can be included at the root level of your application CSS. Then simply use `var(--inch)` on the stylesheets for layout, like so:

/* Desktop instance */

.heroBanner {
width: 100%;
height: calc(1/3 * var(--inch)); /* 1/3rd of an inch in height. */
}

I have turned this idea into an open-source [polyfill](https://github.com/bookiza/--inch) that covers some of the devices of the day. Feel free to fork and submit PRs to add newer `--inch: pixels` mappings if a device-browser combination isn't already covered.